# tcsh scripting - keep newlines of grep results

Tags: grep, tcsh

I am writing a simple script in tcsh (apparently that's a bad idea, but well) to grep some patterns from a text file. Say we have a file `animal_names.txt` which consists of:

```
dog carrot
dog bolt
cat larry
cat brownies
bird parry
bird pirate
```

and I wrote the script:

```
set animals = "dog\|cat"
set names = `grep $animals animal_names.txt`
echo "$names"
```

The intention was to grep all lines with "dog" or "cat". However, the output I get is just oneline:

```
dog carrot dog bolt cat larry cat brownies
```

Somehow the newlines were removed at the output. Is there a way to keep the newlines? Another [post](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/284220/tcsh-preserve-newlines-in-command-substitution) suggested to use the :q modifier, but it doesn't work in my case.

Comment: Can't you just not use tcsh? You can run sh scripts from within a tcsh shell session so there's no reason to use tcsh for scripting. As you point out, (t)csh is just a bad scripting tool.

Comment: maybe related: https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/532984/how-to-make-tcsh-multiline-prompt-use-newline-character

Answer (score 5, accepted):

"*the output I get is just one line*" - unfortunately you've just hit one of the reasons why scripting in `[t]csh` is problematic. Keeping newlines is either not possible or [non-trivial](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/284226/100397). Use `bash` (or `sh`) instead.

Assume this is written to the file `find_animals`:

```
#!/bin/sh
animals='dog|cat'
names=$(grep -E "$animals" animal_names.txt)
echo "$names"
```

Notice I've not escaped the RE `|` symbol but instead told `grep` to use Extended Regular Expressions (ERE). You could leave it as per your original but I think it's easier to read this way.

Make the script executable

```
chmod a+x find_animals
```

Run it in the directory where your `animal_names.txt` file can be found

```
./find_animals
```

Output

```
dog carrot
dog bolt
cat larry
cat brownies
```

If you insist on using `tcsh` this will work:

```
#!/usr/bin/tcsh -f
set animals = 'dog|cat'
set temp = "`grep -E '$animals' animal_names.txt`"
set names = ""
set nl = '\
'
foreach i ( $temp:q )
    set names = $names:q$i:r:q$nl:q
end
set names = $names:r:q
echo $names:q
```

References

- [tcsh preserve newlines in command substitution `…`](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/284226/100397) (a non-trivial solution that works)
- [Csh Programming Considered Harmful](https://www-uxsup.csx.cam.ac.uk/misc/csh.html)
- [Top Ten Reasons not to use the C shell](https://www.grymoire.com/unix/CshTop10.txt)